# What is the best design practice when you have a class where properties are dependent on a web service call?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

If I have a class with some read-only properties that are populated by a web service call, what is considered the best way to design this?

Is it considered proper for the property getters to make the web service call.  It seems that the downside of this is that the getter is doing more than one thing and obscures the expense of the call.  I realize that any of the property getters only needs to make the web service call once (by checking for nulls or flag before making the call).  But that a single property getter could potentially be setting the private fields for other properties seems to smell to me.

On the other hand if I have have a public method (ie InitWebServiceVals) that calls the web service and updates the private fields I am creating a temporal dependency between the method and the property getters.  So the API obscures the fact that you shouldn't read a property until the "InitWebServiceVals" is called.

Or is there some other method or pattern that addresses this? For example, making the webservice call in the constructor?  Or is this generally indicative of a design issue?

I have run into this issue a number of times and I always ended up preferring the second method to the first.

Any thoughts?

Seth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would throw one other option at you.  You could use a factory (either a class or static method) to instance your class.  The factory would be responsible for making the web service calls and handing off the property values to the class (either through a parameterized constructor on your class that accepts the values, or by declaring the setters as internal).

This would have the added benefit of decoupling the "how does my class get those values" part from the class itself.

So:

```
var myClass = MyClass.Create(); // where create is a static
// or
var myClass = MyClassFactory.Create(); // using a separate factory
// or
var myClass = MyClass.CreateFromTestData(value1, value2, value3); // etc
```

Comment: A factory wouldn't allow for lazy instantiation, though, which is one of the options he's asking about.  I assume, from the question, that there's a possibility he doesn't want to take the hit of a service call if the data isn't needed (possibly there's other data in the object that comes from another source).

Comment: @Ragoczy my read of the post was that one of the options that Seth was thinking about was using a constructor, and he was questioning whether it was good to perform this initialization lazily because the property getter was hiding work and latency.  This is definitely not a lazy init, but I think that it is a better solution than putting the logic in the constructor, which was one of Seth's options.

Comment: I'm just not seeing what added value a Factory gives in this instance. In fact, having thought about it, it seems likely that the best course would be to get that service call into a background thread (in general and not knowing the specifics of this object's usage).

Comment: The factory decouples the logic of getting the values from whatever work the class is really doing.  This could be useful if you ever need to alter the means that you use to retrieve the values (examples might be injecting test values, using locally cached values, or perhaps directing to a different URL).  The asynchronous pattern could be really interesting as well, but now you do have a new problem -- you have to design additional handling for when a service call fails. (probably raise an exception when one of failed properties is accessed)

Comment: So I'd probably use mocks and dependency injection for most of that instead of a factory, and then handling a failure of the service call would have to depend on what I want the behavior to be (which has to be decided whether the call's synch or asynch): Is it fatal to my business logic? Are there default values I can use? Cached Values? Should it retry? Etc.

Comment: Each of those points is a reason that you would not want to tightly couple the retrieval of those values within your business class.  And, whether you want to use a mock, DI, or a factory, you are talking about decoupllng (or, with the mock, intercepting) the logic for retrieval of those values from the intrinsic logic within that class.  Every point that you make is a reason why I would recommend against coupling the service access with the getter logic within the properties.

Comment: Factory is completely wrong practice, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9390024/235715

Answer (score 2):

I would use lazy initializers. There is full support for them baked into the .NET framework. See [Lazy(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid the second solution (InitWebServiceVals), because of the requirement that the consumer know about it and take an extra action.  I would either make the web service call in the object's constructor *or* when the first property is accessed, depending on when you want to take the hit of accessing the web service.

Having the access of Property A make the service call and also set the values for Properties B, C, and D is okay, it's lazy instantiation and perfectly justified if the call is better deferred until first needed.

EDIT:

So after some additional thought, there's a third option which I like a little better, depending on the intended use of the object.  If there are potentially multiple web services generating the property values, or property values that *don't* come from web services and should be available immediately, or even that it's likely the object will be instantiated and not accessed immediately, then having the constructor make the service call asynchronously and making the property getters smart enough to wait for that call to finish would offload the cost of the service call to another thread.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, having property getters (or setters) doing anything computationally expensive is a bad idea.  When I see a property, I generally assume that it is going to be a fast, simple operation.

Comment: I agree with the first part of your message. Getters should be fast they mimic reading of variables and this is fast operations.

Comment: I disagree with the second part of my message, now that I've thought about it.  Doesn't solve the problem at all, really.  Removed it.

Comment: @SteveCzetty: Having the first call to a property be computationally expensive shouldn't be an issue if subsequent calls will be cheap (a deciding factor IMHO for methods versus properties is whether callers should be encouraged to go through the trouble of caching the return value; if properties cache themselves, there's little need for callers to do so).  A bigger issue is that things which can throw exceptions should generally be methods rather than properties, and attempts to access remote machines cannot be guaranteed to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that a form of the [Factory Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx) and return the Class from a "Create" type of static method, this allows you to separate the WebService side should you change how you are retrieving the data, from Web Service to Restful etc it also makes it easier to impliment unit testing, asyncronous lazy loading etc as well as testing. You could also easily use an IOC container or Dependency Injection to inject the Service API at runtime.

To clarify the testing, if you define an interface with the Create Method you can simple "swap" or "Inject" out the Interface implementation.

```
public MyClass webServiceClass = IMyFactoryInterface.Create();

public static MyClassFactory : IMyFactoryInterface
{
    public static MyClass Create(params anyParametersRequired)
    {    
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making the web service call in the constructor, so that the performance hit is taken before anyone asks for a property.  If you don't want to take the hit immediately on construction, then you could at least start the web service call async in the constructor, and have the property get block until the data is available.

Rico Mariani has an excellent post about how you shouldn't do ANYTHING expensive in a property get, since getting a property value should be a cheap operation.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2011/12/19/performance-guidelines-for-properties.aspx

Comment: Constructors should be cheap as well; in fact I'd argue it would be even more inappropriate to have a constructor perform a webservice call than it would be for properties

Comment: I agree, they should be cheap, but when you *create* something, it is understandable to have some initialization cost; whereas a property should return almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would avoid creating the object and then setting properties. A better solution is to create a higher-level provider that returns the object you want in a fully initialized state. If that service needs to call into a webservice then so be it. This lets you avoid the temporal dependency *and* has the advantage of communicating that getting the object an expensive operation.

Example:
ISomeService.Get() returns a Widget
ISuperWidgetProvider.Get() returns a SuperWidget by calling into  ISomeService, getting a few properties, and getting the rest from some other data source.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on multiple factors:

- reaction time of getter (what is allowed time delay for getter)
- whether service is sync or async
- how "heavy" is service call
- how often the results of service call change
- how often to you expect you code to call this getter

Answer is pretty clear and simple if answer this questions.

There are three main strategies to help you:

- caching
- lazy initialization
- constructor initialization

Update: I feel like your are trying to solve caching problem inside some "working" class that is not supposed to do this, if it is the case you need to introduce a CachingMyService wrapper around the service, that will be used by you client code.